# How to get thelist of Azure Advisor recommendations using API

Tags: python, azure, powerbi, azure-advisor

I have been getting authorization error while trying to do the following:

[Error]

> {'error': {'code': 'AuthorizationFailed',
> 'message': "The client '***' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/action' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

[Code]

```
Get_Token_Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantID%7D/oauth2/token"
payload = {
"client_id": "**",
"client_secret":"**",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
}
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.post(Get_Token_Url, headers=headers, data=payload)
df = json.loads(response.content)
Token = df\['access_token'\]

url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionID%7D/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2023-01-01"

headers = {
'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
df1 = json.loads(response.content)
df1
```

Please let me know how to get the Azure advisor recommendation via API that will eventually be used in Power BI report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD application named `SriOctSP` and added below **API permission**:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as the service principal does not have any roles under subscription:

```py
Get_Token_Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantID%7D/oauth2/token"
payload = {
"client_id": "**",
"client_secret":"**",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
}
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.post(Get_Token_Url, headers=headers, data=payload)
df = json.loads(response.content)
Token = df\['access_token'\]

url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionID%7D/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2023-01-01"

headers = {
'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
df1 = json.loads(response.content)
df1
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I assigned **`Reader`** role to the service principal under subscription like this:

[image]

When I ran the below modified code with `get` request after assigning role to service principal, I got the **response** successfully as below:

```py
import requests
import json

Get_Token_Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token"
payload = {
"client_id": "appId",
"client_secret":"secret",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
}
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.post(Get_Token_Url, headers=headers, data=payload)
df = json.loads(response.content)
Token = df['access_token']

url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/sub_id/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2023-01-01"

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df1 = json.loads(response.content)
print(df1)
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Permissions in Azure Advisor | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/permissions)

Comment: That worked like a champ, thank you!